# How can I mouse camera view by mouse for fps in unity 5

Tags: c#, camera

I am just looking into Unity5 since it is my school project. They told me to make a fps game and I try to make a fps that will make the camera rotate by Q and E but I cannot move the camera by mouse. And when I want to input mouse , I can not move my fps character at all. Here my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

private MazeCell currentCell;

private MazeDirection currentDirection;

public void SetLocation (MazeCell cell) {
    if (currentCell != null) {
        currentCell.OnPlayerExited();
    }
    currentCell = cell;
    transform.localPosition = cell.transform.localPosition;
    currentCell.OnPlayerEntered();
}

private void Move (MazeDirection direction) {
    MazeCellEdge edge = currentCell.GetEdge(direction);
    if (edge is MazePassage) {
        SetLocation(edge.otherCell);
    }
}

private void Look (MazeDirection direction) {
    transform.localRotation = direction.ToRotation();
    currentDirection = direction;
}

private void Update () {



    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        Move(currentDirection);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
        Move(currentDirection.GetNextClockwise());
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
        Move(currentDirection.GetOpposite());
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
        Move(currentDirection.GetNextCounterclockwise());
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q)) {
        Look(currentDirection.GetNextCounterclockwise());
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
        Look(currentDirection.GetNextClockwise());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should remoove the "else if"s in your update function and replace them with a simple "if".
because what happens is that the following functions are skipped as soon as one of your if statements is true.
that should fix it.

Comment: anyway i assume you're new in coding so here one suggestion: don't ever use esle if in your code just use if{}else{if{...}}. it makes things much more simpler :D

Comment: sry was pressing enter to soon xD

Comment: I delete it already. because it make my game freeze when I press play

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
//Position of mouse since last change in viewdirection
private float mousePosLast;

//Tollerance of mouse input 
//this is optional but makes the the input not that sensitive
public float mouseTollerance;

//sets the correct position of mouse on start
public void Start () {
    mousePosLast = Input.mousePosition.x;
}


public void Update () {
    /*
    ...other update code...
    */

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q)) {
               Look(currentDirection.GetNextCounterclockwise());
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
            Look(currentDirection.GetNextClockwise());
        }

    //check if change in mouse position is big enougth to trigger camera rotation
    if(Mathf.Abs(Input.mousePosition.x - mousePosLast) > mouseTollerance){
        //check whether to turn right or left
        if(Input.mousePosition.x - mousePosLast > 0){
            Look(currentDirection.GetNextCounterclockwise());
        }else{
            Look(currentDirection.GetNextClockwise());
        }
    }
}

private void Look (MazeDirection direction) {
        transform.localRotation = direction.ToRotation();
       currentDirection = direction;

    //set mousePosLast to current mouseposition on every change -> avoids strange effects
    mousePosLast = Input.mousePosition.x;
}
```

}

Comment: wow it make me l see through the walls of the game but thanks anyways.

Comment: maybe you should look over your entire code.. there might be some issues that aren't caused by your Player class directily.

Comment: whats about your mazeCell, mazePassage,...? try the debugger of monodevelop http://docs.unity3d.com/432/Documentation/Manual/Debugger.html or use Debug.Log(); to log the important variables.